# Create an empty Query in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I have a sitation where I want to execute different queries based on some conditions, and sometimes return a query that results in an empty result set.

```
def myQuery(something: Boolean): Query[A, B, Seq] = {
  if(something)
    for {
       x <- table
       y <- othertable
       // ...
    } yield a
   else
     Query.empty
}
```

However, `Query.empty` is of type `Query[Unit, Unit, Seq]`. Causing me to have to write this:

```
def myQuery(): Query[A, B, Seq] = {
  if(something)
    for {
       x <- table
       y <- othertable
       // other logic yielding a moderatly complex `A` and `B` 
    } yield b
  else
    for {
      x <- table
      y <- othertable
      // Parts of logic copy pasted
      if false
    } yield b
}
```

Is there an easier/clearer way to generate a correctly typed empty `Query`?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise using `Option[Query[A,B,Seq]]` in this case as your return type, but that's without much context.

(edited since the original answer was wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You can try moving your condition to the for comprehension itself like

```
for {
  x <- table
  y <- othertable
  ...
  if something
} yield b
```

With "Hello, Slick" Activator template:

```
val q = for {
  c <- coffees
  if cond
} yield c

val future = db.run(q.result).map(println)
Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```

When `cond` is `true`, it prints

> background log: info: Vector((Colombian,101,7.99,0,0), (French_Roast,49,8.99,0,0), (Espresso,150,9.99,0,0), (Colombian_Decaf,101,8.99,0,0), (French_Roast_Decaf,49,9.99,0,0))

When `false`,

> background log: info: Vector()

`Coffees` table def is

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag)
  extends Table[(String, Int, Double, Int, Int)](tag, "COFFEES")
```

Type of `q` is correctly inferred as `Query[Coffees, (String, Int, Double, Int, Int), Seq]`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and solved it using the [take method](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/api/index.html#slick.lifted.Query@take(num:Long):slick.lifted.Query[E,U,C]).

```
def myQuery(): Query[A, B, Seq] = {
    val query = for {
       x <- table
       y <- othertable
       // other logic yielding a moderatly complex `A` and `B` 
    } yield b

    if(something)
        query
    else
        query.take(0)
```

Really, Query.empty should just allow type arguments